# How to Replace the app icon with the new drawer animation on API19 and lower devices?

Tags: android

I have a problem with the new Animation from the drawer look here on the G+post from me: [Link to the Picture](https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-QSUogKPQ5h0/VEPWJNq23zI/AAAAAAAAHZ8/wA5xZNN_Mns/w481-h855-no/Screenshot_2014-10-19-17-12-57.png)

How can I replace the app icon with the new drawer animation on API19 and lower devices? I want it to look like the ones from PlayStore, Newstand, etc.

Comment: Rather than link your G+Post, please include your information directly.

Comment: Where i written that post i had the image in it but i need 10 repurtation to post a picture. So i linked the g+ Post

Comment: one more up vote and you will have your rep :). Try to fix the link then.  Thanks for becoming involved!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to need the new support V7 library and will need to set the Action Bar Drawer Toggle as such - with `this` being your activity/context:

```
ActionBarDrawerToggle navigationToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,navigationDrawerLayout,R.string.nav_drawer_open,R.string.nav_drawer_closed);
navigationDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(navigationToggle);
```

Where ActionBarDrawerToggle is inherited from `android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle`

It is absolutely necessary that your new Activity extend `ActionBarActivity` provided by `android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity` otherwise the action bar will not show up. You'll likely have to adjust all your action bar references from `getActionBar()` to `getSupportActionBar()`. Let me know if there's anything I can help with as I just transitioned 2 apps into the new guidelines using the SupportV7 library.

Comment: I have my Drawer written down in my main activity and i extend ActionBarActivity from there? When i do that i get following exception ` Process: com.rr.angelninbb, PID: 16466 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.rr.angelninbb/com.rr.angelninbb.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity. ` or I have you misunderstood?

Comment: Correct. Your main activity will need to extend ActionBarActivity and you're going to need to extend the Material theme from AppCompat in order for this to work properly. So in your styles.xml your root theme element should look something like this: 

`<style name="YourThemeName" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">STYLES</style>`

Comment: Thanks it work how i change now the background color it is now gray of the actionbar?

Comment: Add an action bar style to the root element, then define the background inside of that (without the 'android:' element). See below:

`<style name="YourThemeName" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
<item name="actionBarStyle">@style/YourThemeName.ActionBar</item>
</style>
<style name="YourThemeName.ActionBar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="background">@color/primary</item>
    </style>`

Answer (score 1):

What is stated by Logan is correct but it does not require that much changed.

If you already have a drawer then you will most likely have code similar to this.

```
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
//some other code
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, mDrawerLayout,
            R.drawable.ic_drawer,  /* nav drawer icon to replace 'Up' caret */
            R.string.drawer_open,
            R.string.drawer_close)
```

If so then all you need to do is to remove the line that is comment above, and change to the v7 library, so that you get something like this.

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
//some other code
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, mDrawerLayout,
            R.string.drawer_open,
            R.string.drawer_close)
```

There is no need to change to inherit anything other than the standard Activity; and using a theme such as holo.light.darkactionbar or any other action bar related theme works just fine.

Comment: Yes, i know it before i ask. The only problem was that what you see in the picture. But thanks for this addition, maybe it help some other people that have these problem, too. :)